# 'Kilimanjaro volcano' or 'The Kilimanjaro volcano'?

Tags: definite-article

Could you tell me why do I need to add article 'the' in this sentence?

> The last eruption of **the** Kilimanjaro volcano happened about 200
> years ago.

It's taken from an English app. The word in bold is the answer suggested by the app. The original options are (an/the/-/a). I chose (-) (no additional article), but my answer was marked wrong. There's also the lesson section to review some topic related to the test given. It says:

> Names of countries in the singular, summits of mountains, continents,
> towns don't use the definite article:
>
> - Mount Whitney
> - Mount McKinley
>
> Names of countries in the plural, mountain ranges, regions use the
> definite article:
>
> - **the** Rocky Mountains
> - **the** Alps

Do we need it because **THE** before a noun is required when the other person knows which thing we are referring to? OALD defines *a volcano* as a mountain with a large opening at the top through which gases and lava (= hot liquid rock) are forced out into the air, or have been in the past. If that the case, shouldn't the answer be (-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name "Kilimanjaro" is being used as a modifier in this phrase.  It modifies the word "volcano".

"The" is used, because the word "volcano" needs an article.  It would need an article even if the modifier was removed:

> The last eruption of *the* volcano was 200 years ago.

The presence of a name doesn't change the need for an article. The use of articles with proper nouns is irrelevant. The article is for the word "volcano", not for the proper noun "Kilimanjaro".